# PostgreSQL 9.3 Partitions Not Working

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I have a table, e, with range partitions setup daily.  The main table and partition tables have been defined like so.

```
CREATE TABLE e (
  toi TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
WITH (
 OIDS=TRUE
);

CREATE TABLE e_20150501
CONSTRAINT e_20150501_toi_chk CHECK (toi >= ‘2015-05-01’::DATE AND toi < ‘2015-  05-02’::DATE)
INHERITS (e)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
```

For some reason, no matter how I construct my WHERE clause in SELECTs, I can’t seem to get a plan that doesn't Seq Scan every single partition table?

I’ve tried …

```
WHERE toi::DATE >= ‘2015-05-01’::DATE AND toi::DATE <= ‘2015-05-02’::DATE;

WHERE toi >= to_timestamp(‘2015-05-01 12:30:57’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS’) AND toi <= to_timestamp(‘2015-05-02 12:30:57’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS’);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are mixing dates and timestamps. You should define your check constraint to use a timestamp as well: `CHECK (toi >= timestamp '2015-05-01 00:00:00' ...` And then use timestamps in your query as well.

Comment: So I should define my partition table like so?
    CREATE TABLE e_20150501
    CONSTRAINT e_20150501_toi_chk CHECK (toi >= ‘2015-05-01     00:00:00’::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AND toi < ‘2015-  05-02 00:00:00’::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
    INHERITS (e)
    WITH (
      OIDS=TRUE
    );

Comment: I have tested this and it appears to fix my problems.  Can I simply drop the existing constraint and add the updated one on the partition tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `SET constraint_exclusion = on;` without it set in your table definition all queries will scan all table partitions.

see the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) section 5.9.4. Partitioning and Constraint Exclusion

Comment: Actually, turning it on is most likely a bad idea. The default `partition` mode is the preferred (see at the bottom of 5.9.4).

Comment: It is set to PARTITION in postgresql.conf, so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The fist comment on my original post was correct.

> You are mixing dates and timestamps. You should define your check constraint to use a timestamp as well: `CHECK (toi >= timestamp '2015-05-01 00:00:00' ...` And then use timestamps in your query as well. –  a_horse_with_no_name